# Detect Swipe without affecting click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did some researches on other posts related to swipe functionality and found a useful function however it also affects click events.

Here is the link I found that is swipe function useful:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml

Is there a way to tweak it and to make click event work.

Here is the sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8rscLo1z/4/ (P.S. Use toggle device toolbar in chrome to work)

Swipe trigger:

```
var el = document.getElementById('testing_area');
swipedetect(el, function(swipedir){
    // swipedir contains either "none", "left", "right", "top", or "down"
    if (swipedir =='left'){
        $('#testing_area').html('Swipe LEFT detected');
    } else if (swipedir == 'right'){
        $('#testing_area').html('Swipe RIGHT detected');
    } else {
        $('#testing_area').html('Swipe UNRECOGNIZED');
    }
});
```

Click event

```
$('#testing_area').click(function(){
    alert('test click');
});
```

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869569/how-to-track-mousepress-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your touchend event listener, var distX pertains to the distance travelled by the touch (swipe). You can add additional **if condition** wherein it will check if distX is equal to 0.

Update you code from:

```
touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX 
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime 
        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ 
                swipedir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right' 
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){
                swipedir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down'
            }
        }
        handleswipe(swipedir)
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
```

Into this

```
touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX 
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY 
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime 
        if(distX == 0){ 
            alert('test click'); //this is where click event is detected
        } else if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ 
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ 
                swipedir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right' 
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ 
                swipedir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : '
            }
        }
        handleswipe(swipedir)
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8rscLo1z/14/show